# header location not working on online godaddy hosting but working on local host

Tags: php, mysqli, localhost, hosting

the header location work perfect on local host but on godaddy hosting online not work how can i solve this problem this my login code

```
ob_start();
      include("includes/connect.php");
    if(isset($_POST['login'])){

$username=strip_tags(mysqli_escape_string($conn,$_POST["txt_username"]));
$pass=strip_tags(mysqli_escape_string($conn,$_POST["txt_pass"]));
if($username=="" || $pass=="")
{
echo"Enter Username And Password.";
}else{
$sql=mysqli_query($conn,"select* from tbl_user where db_username='$username' and db_pass='$pass'")or die(mysqli_error($conn));
$count = mysqli_num_rows($sql);
$res=mysqli_fetch_array($sql);
if($count==1){  
    $query=mysqli_query($conn,"update tbl_user set db_isonline='1' where db_username='$username'")or die(mysqli_error($conn));
    $user=$res['db_username'];
$_SESSION["username"]=$res['db_username'];
$_SESSION["level"]=$res['db_level'];
$_SESSION['LAST_ACTIVITY'] = time();  
header("location:main.php");exit();
}else{ echo"Username Or Password Incorrect";}
}
    }
   ob_end_flush();
```

main page code

```
    ob_start();
include("includes/connect.php");
 if(isset($_SESSION['username'])){ 
 $username=$_SESSION['username'];echo $_SESSION["username"];
 $query=mysqli_query($conn,"select* from tbl_user where db_username='$username'")or die(mysqli_error($conn));
 $res=mysqli_fetch_array($query);
 $fname=$res['db_fname'];
 $lname=$res['db_lname'];
 }else{
 if(!isset($_SESSION['username']) || $_SESSION['username']==""  ){
 header("location:index.php");}} 
     ob_end_flush();
```

and i have some php code in my header that is

```
     ob_start();
    session_start();

    if(empty($_SESSION['username'])) {
        echo'
        <nav class="navbar navbar-default" role = "navigation">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="main.php"><img src="img/t-square-logo-Final.png" alt="the professionals" width="200px" style="float:left;margin-top:41px;" /></a>
    </div>
    <div class = "collapse navbar-collapse" id = "example-navbar-collapse">
         </div>
  </div></div>
</nav>
   </div>';
    }
    else{
        if($_SESSION['level']==0){
        echo'
        <nav class="navbar navbar-default" role = "navigation">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar-header">
    <button type = "button" class = "navbar-toggle" 
         data-toggle = "collapse" data-target = "#example-navbar-collapse">
         <span class = "sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
         <span class = "icon-bar"></span>
         <span class = "icon-bar"></span>
         <span class = "icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="main.php"><img src="img/t-square-logo-Final.png" alt="the professionals" width="200px" style="float:left;margin-top:41px;" /></a>
    </div>
    <div class = "collapse navbar-collapse" id = "example-navbar-collapse">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
      <li ';?><?php if ($page_name=="search.php") 
echo"class=\"active\""; ?><?php echo'><a href="search.php">Order</a></li>
<li><a href="task/task.php?action=">Task</a></li>
      <li><a href="logout.php">Logout</a></li> 
    </ul>
  </div>
  </div></div>
</nav>
   </div>';}ob_end_flush();
```

i use this to print the error

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
```

and this is the error i have but i don't know how to solve it
Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /home/mhmd2991/public_html/index.php:2) in /home/mhmd2991/public_html/index.php on line 39

Comment: remove the space after <?php tag

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to fix "Headers already sent" error in PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8028957/how-to-fix-headers-already-sent-error-in-php)

Comment: @parag I don't have any space after <?php or ?>

Comment: your script may echoing something before the headers